# Problem with custom tabs in android

Tags: android, tabs

Anyone know What image to I need to include to get rid of the small silver line at the bottom of the dark red tab in the picture?

[image: tabs with silver bottom border]

This is how I'm changing the tab background:

```
public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
   ...
    setTabTheme();
    tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener (otc);   

   ...
}

// handler for tab changes to make sure our images are loaded
OnTabChangeListener otc = new OnTabChangeListener()
{
   @Override
   public void onTabChanged (String tabId)
   {
      setTabTheme();
   }
};


private void setTabTheme()
{
   tabHost = getTabHost();
   TabWidget twid = tabHost.getTabWidget();

   // set tab color
   for(int i=0; i < tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount(); i++)
   {
      // unselected icon
      Drawable tabd = (Drawable) getResources ().getDrawable (R.drawable.tabsel_dkred_big_9);
      tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundDrawable (tabd);

      // need to figure out which one to make gray text...
      Log.d (TAG, "this widget focused : " + twid.isFocused ());

      // tab text
      RelativeLayout rLayout = (RelativeLayout) twid.getChildAt(i);

      if (rLayout.getChildCount () > 0)
      {
         TextView tv = ((TextView) rLayout.getChildAt(1));
         tv.setTextColor (Color.WHITE);

         // refer to res/style for text appearance
         tv.setTextAppearance(getBaseContext (), R.style.CustomText);
         Log.d (TAG, "text is " + tv.getText ().toString ());

      }
   }

   // set selected  tab
   Drawable tabd = (Drawable) getResources ().getDrawable (R.drawable.tabsel_red_big_9);
   tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(tabHost.getCurrentTab()).setBackgroundDrawable (tabd); 
}
```